# Wcf service Error

Tags: wcf, service

When i am trying send large size files through wcf service, its give Unexpected sercice response, bad request 400 error. if i send bellow 16000 bytes size files does not give error. how do i increase the size, and help me to resolve the issue. 
Thanks to all.
by
Senthil

Answer (score 1):

In your binding on the server for the service endpoint, find your transport binding element and increase the value for the following two attributes.

```
maxReceivedMessageSize="999999" 
maxBufferSize="999999"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're hitting a quota or throttle, check out e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463275.aspx

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/20/how-to-throttle-a-wcf-service-help-prevent-dos-attacks-and-maintain-wcf-scalability/

http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2006/11/21/tuning-service-throttles.aspx